# How can I detect last digits in python string

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I need to detect last digits in the string, as they are indexes for my strings. They may be 2^64, So it's not convenient to check only last element in the string, then try second... etc.
String may be like `asdgaf1_hsg534`, i.e. in the string may be other digits too, but there are somewhere in the middle and they are not neighboring with the index I want to get.

Comment: Did you try to write something?

Comment: Can you post an example input/output?

Comment: I have strings as an input, and I have to pass last digits in the string to other function as an argument. So I need to parse these strings and get last digits. strings are like in the question - "asdgaf1_hsg534", "asdfh23_hsjd12", "dgshg_jhfsd86", etc. For mentioned strings I need to get 534, 12 and 86 from mentioned strings

Comment: i just wrote an answer and deleted it. you should really try it yourself. it is good practise for beginners :)

Comment: 534 is not a digit. it's a number

Comment: 5 3 and 4 are last digits in the string

Comment: suggest you show what code you do have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a method using `re.sub`:

```
import re

input = ['asdgaf1_hsg534', 'asdfh23_hsjd12', 'dgshg_jhfsd86']

for s in input:
    print re.sub('.*?([0-9]*)$',r'\1',s)
```

**Output:**

```
534
12
86
```

**Explanation:**

The function takes a `regular expression`, a `replacement string`, and the `string` you want to do the replacement on: `re.sub(regex,replace,string)`

The regex `'.*?([0-9]*)$'` matches the whole string and captures the number that precedes the end of the string. Parenthesis are used to capture parts of the match we are interested in,  `\1` refers to the first capture group and `\2` the second ect..

```
.*?      # Matches anything (non-greedy) 
([0-9]*) # Upto a zero or more digits digit (captured)
$        # Followed by the end-of-string identifier
```

So we are replacing the whole string with just the captured number we are interested in. In python we need to use raw strings for this: `r'\1'`. If the string doesn't end with digits then a blank string with be returned.

---

```
twosixfour = "get_the_numb3r_2_^_64__18446744073709551615"

print re.sub('.*?([0-9]*)$',r'\1',twosixfour)

>>> 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex can detect digits at the end of the string:

```
'\d+$'
```

`$` matches the end of the string. `\d+` matches one or more digits.  The `+` operator is greedy by default, meaning it matches as many digits as possible.  So this will match *all* of the digits at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it:
                
is_match = re.match(r'(.*)(\D)(\d+)', myString)
if is_match:
    print is_match.group(3)

It works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `re.sub` and make sure that there is at least a single digit present at the end of the line, you can use the quantifier `+` to match 1 or more digits `\d+` to not remove the whole line if there are no digits present or no digits only at the end of the line.

```
^.*?(\d+)$
```

- `^` Start of line
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possible (non greedy)
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `$` End of line

Or using a negative lookbehind

```
^.*(?<!\d)(\d+)$
```

- `^` Start of line
- `.*` Match any char except a newline as much as possible
- `(?<!\d)(\d+)` Assert no digits directly to the left, then capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jqGF9A/1)

When using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match), you can omit the `^` anchor and you might also use `\A` and `\Z` to asert the [start and the end of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519318/regex-differences-between-and-a-z).

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QyYg0c/1)

```
import re

strings = ['asdgaf1_hsg534', 'asdfh23_hsjd12', 'dgshg_jhfsd86', 'test']

for s in strings:
    print (re.sub(r".*?(\d+)$", r'\1',s))
```

Output

```
534
12
86
test
```

---

If there should be a non digit present before matching a digit as in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471976/how-can-i-detect-last-digits-in-python-string#comment18432253_13473178) you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) with a single capture group.

```
^.*[^\d\r\n](\d+)
```

- `^` Start of line
- `.*` Match any char except a newline as much as possible
- `[^\d\r\n]` Negated character class, match any char except a digit or a newline
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tgLaDT/1)

---

To get the last digits in the string (not necessarily at the end of the string)

```
^.*?(\d+)[^\r\n\d]*$
```

- `^` Start of line
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possible (non greedy)
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `[^\r\n\d]*` Negated character class, match 0+ times any char except a newline or digit
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aUNeWe/1)