# REGEX - Differences between `^`, `$` and `\A`, `\Z`

Tags: python, regex

As I know, `re` proposes the following boundary matches.

- `^` matches at the beginning of a line.
- `$` matches at the end of a line.
- `\A` matches the beginning of the input.
- `\Z` matches the end of the input.

Can you give me a concret example showing a real difference between between `^`, `$` and `\A`, `\Z` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference only becomes apparent when you use the [`re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` multiline flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M):

```
>>> re.search(r'^word', 'Line one\nword on line two\n', flags=re.M)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10124f578>
>>> re.search(r'\Aword', 'Line one\nword on line two\n', flags=re.M) is None
True
```

where `^` matched at the start of a *line* (following a newline). `$` matches at the end of a line:

```
>>> re.search(r'word$', 'Line one word\nLine two\n', flags=re.M)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10123e1d0>
>>> re.search(r'word\Z', 'Line one word\nLine two\n', flags=re.M) is None
True
```

From the documentation:

> `re.M`
>   `re.MULTILINE`
>
> When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'` matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, `'^'` matches only at the beginning of the string, and `'$'` only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

`\A` *always* matches at the start of the string regardless, `\Z` always at the end.