# Match repetead pattern sequence in a text

Tags: python, regex

I'm quite new to regular expressions, and cannot figure out how to do what I want. I have a text file as input, and want to extract "articles" from it. The problem is that if I read the text line per line, it cannot cover the entire article since it stops when it encounters a carriage return.

What I would like to do, is to extract everything from a specific pattern until it repeats, whether or not it encounters a carriage return (Python).

Example of sequences :

```
Article ler — NOM
Latius iam disseminata licentia onerosus bonis omnibus Caesar nullum post haec adhibens modum orientis latera cuncta vexabat nec honoratis parcens nec urbium primatibus nec plebeiis.
Article 2 — ANNEE
Nemo quaeso miretur, si post exsudatos labores itinerum longos congestosque adfatim commeatus fiducia vestri ductante barbaricos pagos adventans velut mutato repente consilio ad placidiora deverti.
Article 3 — DATE Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem.
```

And this is the regular expression I have designed : `"^(.*(?=((?i)article(\s\d{1,2})*)).*)"`

As output, I obtain something like that :

```
Article ler — NOM
Article 2 — ANNEE
Article 3 — DATE Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem.
```

The two first ones don't cover the entire article (title + content) : this is my problem.
Does anybody know how to resolve it?

Thanks!

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    label_pattern = ("^(.*(?=((?i)article(\s\d{1,2})*)).*)")

    pattern = re.compile(label_pattern)

    for i, line in enumerate(open('texte.txt')):
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
            print(i+1, match.group(1))
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is possible, read the whole file text and apply the following regex to that text:

```
(?<=Article)[\s\S]*?(?=Article|$)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/quwApD/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=Article)` - positive lookbehind to find the position immediately preceded by the text `Article`
- `[\s\S]*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character(even the newlines). `?` is present to make the match lazy.
- `(?=Article|$)` - Positive lookahead to find the position that is immediately followed by either another `Article` or end-of-full-string represented by `$`

Comment: I got my code to work with this pattern, but I had to change the `$` to a `\Z`. Could it be something with the way strings are read in from a file?

Comment: For an explanation on that, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519318/regex-differences-between-and-a-z)

Comment: Just, is it possible to include the word "Article" in the match? :)

Comment: @Sol Yes, just rewrite the regex as [`Article[\s\S]*?(?=Article|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/quwApD/2)

Comment: Haha, just perfect! However, the "\n" symbol appear in the matches; maybe I can remove it aftermath?

Comment: Hmmm...I don't see any `\n` in the matches. Anyways, `[\s\S]` is going to match anything.

Comment: With "matches = re.findall(label_pattern, file_text)", I have \n in my results; weird...

Comment: @Sol The original text file has `\n` in it, hence you see those in the matches. If you want to remove/replace them, feel free to do so as per your requirement. May be you can replace them with a space or even empty string

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way you are reading the file. If you iterate through the lines in the file, then you won't be able to get multi-line matches. Instead, if you want to use regex, read the whole file in at once.

(Side Note: There may be better ways to achieve this result without using regex.)

```
import re

label_pattern = (r"(?<=^)(article )(\d{1,2})((.)|(\n))+?(?=(^(article)|(\Z)))")

pattern = re.compile(label_pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

file_text = open('texte.txt').read()  # read the whole file

for i, match in enumerate(re.finditer(label_pattern, file_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)):
    print("MATCH %d:\n%s" % (i+1, match.group()))
```

The output is:

```
MATCH 1:
Article 1er - NOM
Latius iam disseminata licentia onerosus bonis omnibus Caesar nullum post haec adhibens modum orientis latera cuncta vexabat nec honoratis parcens nec urbium primatibus nec plebeiis.

MATCH 2:
Article 2 - ANNEE
Nemo quaeso miretur, si post exsudatos labores itinerum longos congestosque adfatim commeatus fiducia vestri ductante barbaricos pagos adventans velut mutato repente consilio ad placidiora deverti.

MATCH 3:
Article 3 - DATE Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem.
```

Also, I assumed that there is a typo in your example text on the first line. You wrote `"Article ler"` but I think you meant "`Article 1er"` (Number `1` instead of letter `l`). If I don't make this change, you won't get the first article since the pattern is looking for "article" followed by 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: In fact, typo is part of the text... There is some noise in :/